# "Storing" a Class to call Static Methods

Tags: c#

Lets say I have Class A, that calls static methods in either Class B or Class C. From which class it will call will depend on a parameter passed in the constructor of Class A. The methods in Class B and C that need to be called have identical method signatures. So, is there any way to do something like:

```
Object call;
if (type == 0)
    call = ClassA;
else
    call = ClassB;

call.someMethod ();
```

I know it can be done using an interface and having both class B and C implement the interface but that would require creating an object of B or C each time the call above happens which is quite resource intensive. So, I would like to know if there are any other ways to do this.

Edit: Sorry if this was not clear, but the `Object call` is a class variable and method calls to Class B and C need to be made in other methods in the class not just the constructor.

Comment: You could use singletons that implement the interface.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to skirt object-orientation here and do functional programming: passing the method of Class B or C to A rather than the full classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use static methods. Use an interface (or a base class), create a single instance of both of your classes and store them in static fields. That way you don't have to instantiate every time, just take an existing instance from the fields.

Comment: I went with approximately this method but just have Class B and C use singletons as the alternative solutions were not really suitable for the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Since the methods are static, I am assuming that we 're talking about helper methods in classes that you do not control (otherwise you could e.g. move them into the same class). In any case, you can use the following approach that works in a variety of circumstances:

Use a variable that holds an [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) pointing to the relevant method. For example:

```
Action action;
if (type == 0) 
    action = ClassA.SomeMethod;
else 
    action = ClassB.SomeOtherMethod;

action();
```

Of course you can also use another delegate type (e.g. the generic versions of `Action`) if you want to pass parameters to the called method.

The one restriction with this approach is that all methods that you might want to call need to have the same signature (number and types of parameters), and the same return type. However you can still work around this by building adapter functions, which is very easy to do using lambdas:

```
// Assume that ClassA.SomeMethod accepts an int parameter
// If you know the value that should be passed, you can adapt it like this:
if (type == 0) 
    action = () => { ClassA.SomeMethod(42); };
```

Comment: Went with another solution because Class B and C have a bunch of static methods that need to be called and storing them all in a separate variable is not really too useful. But upvoted anyways for a good solution (probably better than singletons in most cases) using function pointers.

Comment: @ShardulUpadhyay: You went with the more appropriate solution in my opinion as well. That "bunch of methods" changes the balance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the method call inside your if() statement?

```
if( type == 0 )
{
    ClassA.someMethod();
}
else
{
    ClassB.someMethod();
}
```

If you need to do something with the method's return value, that's still possible by declaring the return object outside the statement and assigning it a value inside the condition blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, using an if else to set a variable to call a common function on. As you are planning to have the if/else anyway, why not just do this...

```
if (type == 0)
    ClassA.SomeMethod();
else
    ClassB.SomeMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample, you are not creating any objects.

The calls are static so creating the object isn't necessary.